# How do I parse through a CSV file and narrow down the list by multiple variables?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, parsing

I have a CSV file with multiple headers such as Name, CPU, Memory, OS, etc. I want to narrow the CSV list by choosing specific parameters for the headers. For example, `if CPU == 2 and Memory == 4GB and OS == Windows`, print out the `Name`.

I'm using python 2.7.

CSV file:

```
Name,CPU,Memory,OS
server1,2,4gb,windows
server2,4,2gb,linux
server3,8,4gb,linux
server4,4,2gb,windows
server5,2,4gb,windows
```

My code:

```
import csv
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line[1])
```

The only thing I can do is read the CPU column. I tried to use if statements but wouldn't work. For example, `if CPU == 2`, `print` doesn't work.

---

Thanks to @gboffi, I got the narrowing portion of the code below:

```
import csv
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:
    dict_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for d in dict_reader:
        if d['CPU'] == '2' and d['OS'] == 'windows' and d['Memory'] == '4gb':
            print(d['Name'])
```

Now the question is, how can I make a user enter the parameters instead of hardcoding them? Also, how can I export the results into a new CSV with all the parameters with the headers?

Answer (score 0):

To answer just your *original* question, here's a good way to do it in Python 2 (note that `namedtuple` wasn't added to the `collections` module until Python 2.6):

```
from __future__ import print_function
from collections import namedtuple
import csv


input_filename = 'test_fields.csv'

with open(input_filename, 'rb') as csv_file:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    fieldnames = next(csvreader)  # Read header row.
    Record = namedtuple('Record', fieldnames)  # Define fieldnames of a record.

    for row in map(Record._make, csvreader):
        if row.CPU == '2' and row.OS == 'windows' and row.Memory == '4gb':
            print(row.Name)
```

Sorry, I don't really understand your follow-on questions about making a user enter the parameters and exporting the results to a new CSV — so suggest you ask a separate question about just those aspects (only after reading the `csv` module's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) to see if you can figure it out yourself (especially the part about writing CSV files).